# Serotonin activity with short 5-HTT promotor region and depression

Tags: genetics, gene-expression, human-genetics, serotonin

So after reading a few studies ([1](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9154246),[2](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/301/5631/386.full)) it seems that a shorter promotor region for the serotonin transport protein may be associated with increased likelihood of developing depression after stressful life events.

I'm still an undergrad but this would seem like it would lead to less transcription of the protein leading to more serotonin at the synapse. My understanding is that this should then lead to some sort protection against mood disorders not the increased likelihood of them like the studies suggest. Is someone able to explain what I'm missing here?

Thanks,

Zane